# Is there a GUID per MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, uuid, guid

I am looking for a way to get a unique ID per database itself. The idea is to exchange objects between different installations of my application. Therefore I have unique IDs for all objects within a single database, but in order to exchange these objects to other databases with the same schema, I introduced a composite ID consisting of a primary and a secondary ID, where the primary is unique within a single database and the secondary should be unique across multiple databases with the same schema.

Does somebody knows a decentralized solution for this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180019/what-is-the-replacement-for-uniqueidentifier-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a global unique identifier for each row solves the problem. Java itself provides a [UUID generator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), but there are more (better) third-party generators as well.