# what datatype to use for MySQL unique key/index

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

Is it ok to use INT as the datatype for the index in MySQL. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go as I fully expect this table to get a lot of entries that will eventually 'overflow' the INT

I doubt something like Facebook uses INT for their index on something such as the wallpost table or something else that would be high traffic /  get lots of entries.

Any thoughts?

Comment: An index speeds up data retrieval; I think you meant to say "primary key" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL`

Comment: The prefix on INT only affects the displayable characters, not the size.

Comment: Why is this the best option? That is still only a finite number.

Comment: @john how many rows will be there???? The `unsigned INT `range is 0 to 4294967295.... is it not enough??

Comment: fair point. I don't think I will have over 4 billion entries in this table

Comment: its same but more efficient way

Comment: i asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256469/what-is-the-benefit-of-zerofill-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

An INT can go up to over 2 **billion** (twice that many if unsigned). If you expect your table to have more rows than that, you can use a BIGINT (which unsigned goes up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615—probably more than even Facebook needs).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you have two choices:

A '[natural key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key)' that reflects the reality of the data you are working with.
For example, a telephone number might be a valid primary key for a calling list, but it would not be appropriate at all for, say, a list of health care beneficiaries because many people might share the same phone number in a home.  Note that a natural key might be made up of more than one field.  For example, the combination of Make, Model, and Year might be a key for a list of automobile models.

A '[surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)' on the other hand, is just an arbitrary value that you assign to a row.  If you go that route, I'd recommend using a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) (UUID in MySql).  [The best way that I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412341/how-should-i-store-guid-in-mysql-tables) to represent those in MySQL is with a char(36) column.  GUIDs are effectively unique forever and can be used infinitely.

If you insist on using a plain old number, then INT is probably fine, or you can use [BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) to be really sure.

```
BIGINT UNSIGNED ZEROFILL
```