# What's the best data type to store 01,02,03 etc. in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

I would like to store numbers like `00`, `01`, `02`, `03`, `04` etc in mySQL.

Which data type would be the best for this?

Comment: What do you want to do with these "numbers".

Comment: I am afraid if I choose wrong type then 01 will turn into 1.

Comment: If you do not plan to do calculations on them; and from your comment it looks that way - store them as any of the string types. Only store them as a number if you plan to do numerical operations on them.

Answer (score 3):

Use `int` to store numbers.

Do not confuse *value* with *rendering*: If you want the numbers *dusplayed* with a leading zero, take care of that in a layer between the data and the user's eyes; do not store rendering *with* the data.

The layer that does the formatting can be anything from the SQL used to select the data right through to javascript in a web page that displays it and anything in between.

Comment: Definitely right. Just add the padding afterwards and do not store numbers as a string, unless they have a string nature, e.g. credit card numbers or so.

Answer (score 1):

These look like codes as opposed to numbers, meaning that you are *not* doing arithmetic operations.  If they are codes, the best way to store them is as `varchar(2)` or `char(2)` types.

If you are treating them as numbers (that is, doing any arithmetic operations), then you should store them as integers (small integers) and append the leading zeros on output.

EDIT:

It is very important to distinguish between strings of digits that are just that -- strings that contain digits -- and actual numbers.  There are many examples of such strings that you definitely want to store as character strings.  Four that come to mind are telephone numbers, American zip codes, account numbers (the account number at my bank starts "057" and the "0" is really, really, really important), and (for the most part) two-part version numbers.

These are distinguished from being actual numbers because you don't do numerical things on them.  That is, you never add them together.  Or increment them.  Or increase the value by 10%.  You do sort them, search for specific values (or even ranges of values), and join on the values.  These are string operations as well as numeric ones.

Your question does not explain what the codes really are.  So, depending on what they represent a character string or number might be appropriate.  However, based on the fact that the "0" is important enough to ask a question about, I definitely lean toward a character representation.

Answer (score 0):

shortly, `varchar`.

Though I don't know what you would do with these "numbers", but if you want to preserve those '0' behind the actual number, you should treat them as string type.

Answer (score 0):

Better use numeric datatypes itself. Specifically ***smallint(2)*** as it is best suited with your samples.

Look here for knowing more about [Numeric Type Attributes in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html).

Also use **ZEROFILL** to append 0 with your data. See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256469/what-is-the-benefit-of-zerofill-in-mysql) thread.