# Creating a DOUBLE Field failed with Error 1064: MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i'm trying to build up a database to learn more about Triggers in MySQL.

So i created an database model with the mysql-workbench. If i try to synchronize the model with the mysql-server, i get a 1064 syntax error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`, `accounts_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_accountA' at line 4


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pzedb`.`accountAmounts` (
  `employee_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `accounts_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `accountAmount` DOUBLE(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`, `accounts_id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_accountAmounts_employee1` (`employee_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_accountAmounts_accounts1` (`accounts_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_accountAmounts_employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id` )
    REFERENCES `pzedb`.`employee` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_accountAmounts_accounts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`accounts_id` )
    REFERENCES `pzedb`.`accounts` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci

SQL script execution finished: statements: 11 succeeded, 1 failed
```

I tried to change the field to VARCHAR and what should i say it worked. I changed other fields to DOUBLE and get the same error.

Is there something wrong or i'm just too stupid to use the workbench?

My OS: Debian 7.1
MySQL: 5.5.31-0+wheezy1
Workbench: 5.2.40 rev 8790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Double` does not accept length. SO in your case it should only be

```
accountAmount DOUBLE NOT NULL
```

For integer, `INT(11)`, it does not mean that the length is 11. It is simply used when [ZEROFILL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256505/491243), which pads the number with `0`, option is specified in DDL. eg

```
INT(4)    INT(4) ZEROFILL
12           0012
122          0122
12222       12222
```

Comment: Seems to be there is a bug in the workbench. I had chosen the DOUBLE without length or something. Thank You for your answer, it works now. BTW. i added this table manually to get it working.