# Adding leading zero to MySQL data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some messy data in a MySQL table that needs clearing. Everything should be either 3 or 4 characters, and those that are two characters need to have a leading zero.

Example Messy Data:

```
23
5351
142
91
4911
1514
53
931
984
```

Which should be:

```
023
5351
142
091
4911
1514
053
931
984
```

I've read that I should use either ZEROFILL or LPAD, but as mine vary in length (3-4) I'm not sure if this is the best method, I worry that 4 character data will be cut short or similar. I would appreciate some direction - thank you.

EDIT: I should add, the Type for this column is mediumint(2). I am free to change this if required.

Comment: if (length(your_field)<3, lpad('0', your_field), your_field) as new_field_value ?

Comment: This is a bad title. It should say, "adding leading zeros in Mysql data presentation". The leading zeros are not here meant to be part of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ZEROFILL as it would meet your requirement of not truncating your data when the length is more than 3. It will only fill 0 if it's shorter than 3.

[What is the benefit of zerofill in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256469/what-is-the-benefit-of-zerofill-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you - the easiest solution, I'm glad I can use ZEROFILL. I have it all working now as MEDIUMINT(4) ZEROFILL

Answer (score 1):

> *I worry that 4 character data will be cut short or similar.*

No. data will not be cut, unless you specify a padding length lesser than the current length of data.

Using `LPAD` the given length is ensured

**Example**:

```
mysql> SELECT LPAD('hi',4,'??');
        -> '??hi' -- result is a string of length 4
-- result data will be cut if padding is less than data length
mysql> SELECT LPAD('hi',1,'??'); 
        -> 'h' -- result is a string of length 1
```

On your data you can specify a length equal to max length of a field data.
If your data supports a max length of 4 digits, then
Try this:

```
SELECT field_name fv, LPAD( field_name, 4, '0' ) lfv from my_table;
```

It would result as below:

```
+------+------+
| fv   | lfv  |
+------+------+
|   23 | 0023 |
| 5351 | 5351 |
|  142 | 0142 |
|   91 | 0091 |
| 4911 | 4911 |
| 1514 | 1514 |
|   53 | 0053 |
|  931 | 0931 |
|  984 | 0984 |
+------+------+
```

**Refer to**: [***Documentation on LPAD***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

Answer (score 1):

LPAD is what you want but you only want to add 0s to numbers that are less than 3 characters long, you can do following:

```
update TABLE set COLUMN = LPAD(COLUMN, 3, '0') where COLUMN < 100
```