# MySQL insert into table with 00001 automatically converts to 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column id INT(11). When I do:

```
insert into table (id) VALUES ('00001');
```

it converts it to 1. I don't mind this behavior but I am wondering if this will change in future versions of mysql. Is there documentation or a reason on why this works?

Comment: what is the datatype for id column ?

Comment: you can set `UNSINGNED ZEROFILL` of fixed length of INT datatype

Comment: if you want to store the values as it is  make the data type for id as varchar2 it must be Integer or Decimal

Comment: Look at this one, i think it will help 
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256469/what-is-the-benefit-of-zerofill-in-mysql

Comment: Well, the number `00001` ***is*** the same as `1`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the `ZEROFILL` flag on the column.  If the flag is set, it adds zeros as padding to your numbers so that they meet the total "width" of the number. So if you have an `INT(3)` and you `INSERT` `1`, you get `001`.

In your case, you probably have an `INT(1)` so it is just truncating your leading zeros because they do not affect the value of the number—only the display of the number.

[What is the benefit of zerofill in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256469/what-is-the-benefit-of-zerofill-in-mysql)

Comment: Ah ok. My integer is NOT zero filled but just wondered why it actually worked. It seems because of the zero fill is why it works (even though I am not using it)