# How to get column specifications from MySQL with Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

In MySQL, every column have flags Binary, Unsigned and Zerofill. Is there a way to get the values of this flags with Java 1.8? DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() doesn't return this values, as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a test table created with

```
CREATE TABLE tableA 
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    w INT(8) ZEROFILL NOT NULL, 
    x INT(8) NOT NULL,
    y int signed not null,
    z int unsigned not null,
    shortBinaryCharString char(10) binary not null,
    myBlob blob(10000) null
);
```

As mostly borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256505) as a starting point.

I would recommend using standard querying against the tables in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database. Such as

```
select table_schema, table_name, column_name, ordinal_position, is_nullable, data_type, 
character_set_name, collation_name, column_type, column_key, extra
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
where table_schema = 'so_gibberish' -- your database/schema name
and table_name='tableA'


+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------------+------------+----------------+
| table_schema | table_name | column_name           | ordinal_position | is_nullable | data_type | character_set_name | collation_name | column_type              | column_key | extra          |
+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------------+------------+----------------+
| so_gibberish | tablea     | id                    |                1 | NO          | int       | NULL               | NULL           | int(11)                  | PRI        | auto_increment |
| so_gibberish | tablea     | w                     |                2 | NO          | int       | NULL               | NULL           | int(8) unsigned zerofill |            |                |
| so_gibberish | tablea     | x                     |                3 | NO          | int       | NULL               | NULL           | int(8)                   |            |                |
| so_gibberish | tablea     | y                     |                4 | NO          | int       | NULL               | NULL           | int(11)                  |            |                |
| so_gibberish | tablea     | z                     |                5 | NO          | int       | NULL               | NULL           | int(10) unsigned         |            |                |
| so_gibberish | tablea     | shortBinaryCharString |                6 | NO          | char      | utf8               | utf8_bin       | char(10)                 |            |                |
| so_gibberish | tablea     | myBlob                |                7 | YES         | blob      | NULL               | NULL           | blob                     |            |                |
+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+--------------------------+------------+----------------+
```

You also may have luck with executing

`SHOW FIELDS FROM tableA;`

or

`show create table tableA`

Using standard java resultsets as you are most likely already doing would suffice.

```
try {
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
      st = con.createStatement();
      rs = st.executeQuery("show fields from tableA");
      while (rs.next()) {
           System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+": "+rs.getString(2));
} catch (SQLException ex) {
     Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(myTest.class.getName());
     lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

---

Note: the reason the character set and collation columns were shown is that there is a nuance difference between having a char binary column with a certain character set sort order. As compared to a true binary blob/text column that has no sort order other than binary. See the Mysql Manual Page entitled [The BINARY and VARBINARY Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html) and determine how that works into your notion of "binary". Often, one has to parse a column of output to determine if zerofill is turned on.