# Alter table column to int(9) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL

Tags: postgresql

After reading the following link..

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94443/how-should-a-numeric-value-that-is-an-external-key-be-stored

I decided to alter a column from text to:

```
int(9) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL
```

However, I am not sure of the SQL statement to use.  I know the below is not correct because it does not include the the 9 digits, unsigned zerofill and not NULL parameters.

```
ALTER TABLE "Organizations" ALTER COLUMN "EIN" TYPE INTEGER using "EIN"::INTEGER
```

UPDATE:
Since Postgres does not use zerofill or INT(9).  What would be the recommended data type of an EIN number that is 9 digits?

Comment: why you think the statement is not correct?.. I would use exactly that one :) at least from first look

Comment: Because it does not show int(9), modify the column to unsigned zero fill and not null.

Comment: use `set not null` for not null, integer does not have variable length and I dont know what zerofill is

Comment: I found this: alter table tablename alter column columnname SET NOT NULL;, but do I need to run it seperately and it still does not alter the column for int(9), unsigned zerofill.

Comment: There is no such thing as `int(9)` in Postgres (or "zerofill"). And if you thought that `int(x)` would define a constraint in MySQL you were wrong to begin with. MySQL will happily store `999999` in an `int(1)` column.

Comment: @user2012677 yes - two separate statements afaik. is zerofill about the fillfactor?..

Comment: @VaoTsun, Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256469/what-is-the-benefit-of-zerofill-in-mysql

Comment: Reading the above and link, what type of store would you recommend?

Comment: ah - so its not fillfactor - it's padding... you want some form of "automatic padding"

Comment: @VaoTsun: `zerofill` (just as the `(9)` part) is a _hint_ for the frontend on how that number should be displayed. Nothing more. The client is free to completely ignore that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah - its not stored in db, but rather smth like `datestyle` for integers?..

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend below as is in two statements:

```
ALTER TABLE "Organizations" ALTER COLUMN "EIN" TYPE INTEGER using "EIN"::INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE "Organizations" ALTER COLUMN "EIN" SET NOT NULL;
```

decoration with padding zeros can be done on select with client (or rule, which would be effectively just a view, selected instead, and thus I think overcomplicating here - ((and changing to int to select text with zeroes - does not sound reasonambe))), eg:

```
t=# select lpad(123::int::text,9,'0');
   lpad
-----------
 000000123
(1 row)
```

so If its needed, can be mocked up

Answer (score 1):

For the 9-digit restriction, a domain over `int` can work:

```
CREATE DOMAIN ein AS int CHECK (VALUE>0 AND VALUE<1000000000);
```

Then `ein` can be used in declarations as a type, for instance:

```
=> CREATE TABLE test(id ein, t text);
CREATE TABLE

=> insert into test values(2*1e9::int);
ERROR:  value for domain ein violates check constraint "ein_check"

=> insert into test values(100);
INSERT 0 1
```

---

The `zerofill` bit is different, it's about presentation, not storage,
and that part cannot be specialized for a domain.

You may instead apply [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) to the values, for example:

```
=> select to_char(id,'000000000') from test;
  to_char  
------------
  000000100
```

and possibly access this through a stored view or a presentation
function that  takes only the `ein` as argument 
if you prefer to abstract this from the client.

To go further, you could create a full type with [`CREATE TYPE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html)
backed with `C` code for the `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` function, and these functions could implement the 9-digit left-padded format as the input/output format, so that the user may never see anything else at the SQL level.