# How to represent a GUID in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, guid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I store GUID in MySQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412341/how-should-i-store-guid-in-mysql-tables)

Hello,

To represent a GUID in MySQL, should I just use varchar?  Also, since it is something that will be used to recognize a user, should it be encrypted?  Or does that lost the point of having the GUID? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412341/how-should-i-store-guid-in-mysql-tables

Comment: Why and how are you using the GUID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a varchar would be a good choice. Maybe even char, because the length is fixed, tough I don't know if you'd gain anything.

And I can't see why you would want to encrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

a GUID is nothing else that a string, so varchar is enough yes. Encryption? No, I don't see the interest, in general we encrypts password in base, not the logins ;)

Comment: A GUID or UUID is not a string, it's a 128 bit number that can be represented as a hexdecimal string and is usually what people read. Storing it as the actual 16 bytes is far better than varchar or any text type.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're coming from a SQL Server background. In MySQL you generally use an INTEGER(10) field with AUTO_INCREMENT as primary key. There's not really any reason to *encrypt* that value in any way.

Comment: In SQL server you too generally use an "identity" column which automatically increments. Arguments for choosing a GUID column over an integer are as valid in MySQL world as in SQL Server world.

Comment: Never saw an identity column before actually. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I've rarely seen anything else as a primary key. :) I know of only one project that used GUIDs, and they only did it because of the massive synchronization they had to do.

Comment: this is not answer to the question