# How to insert Guid for UserId in MySQL Membership DB using ASP.NET Login/SignUp Functionaliy?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Is there any way to achieve inserting GUID in UserID in MYSQL Membership DB's Membership Table.
I tried changing the default USERID from INT(11) to CHAR(16).
But Could not succeed in inserting GUID in that specific column.
Is there any workaround for this.

**Edit:**
Previously I used MSSQL Membership provider. Due to db Size limitation I shifted to MYSQL.

```
ad.UserId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

is the piece of code where I get error because of type casting the present int to guid 
how ever this can be solved simply by removing the (Guid) casting and replacing it with (Id), but my DTO property ad.UserId accepts only GUID.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412341/how-should-i-store-guid-in-mysql-tables

Comment: from the mentioned link only I've changed my INT type to CHAR(16).Please see my comment to your answer.