# What column type of MySQL will return as System.Guid in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I store GUID in MySQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412341/how-should-i-store-guid-in-mysql-tables)

**VARCHAR** will return as `string`
**BLOB** will return as `byte[]`
but, what column type of MySQL will return as **System.Guid** in C#
thanks.
**Edited: I have found the answer**
thanks to DaveHogan that gives me the clue about ORM (Object Relation Mapping)
I started to look for information about the datatype conversion(mapping) made by Connector/NET.
I'm using MySQL Dot Net Connector (Connector/NET)
there are different 3 situations that Connector/NET performs.

Below are what I have found:
**1st Situation:**
Start from Connnector/NET 6.1.1, **CHAR(36)** will be automatically converted as System.GUID in C# and **BINARY(16)** will be treated as System.Byte[].

**2nd Situation:**
If you use older Connector/NET, **BINARY(16)** will be automatically converted as System.GUID when the value is passed into C# and **CHAR(36)** will be treated as System.String.

**3rd Situation:**
If you use newer Connector/NET (newer than 6.1.1), and if you want to use **BINARY(16)** AS System.GUID (be default it is not), you have to add a connection option **Old Guids=true** in the Connection String.
Example:

```
server=localhost;user=root;password=qwerty;database=test;old guids=true;
```

by this, **CHAR(36)** will be converted as System.String and **BINARY(16)** = System.GUID

Read more about connection options of **Old Guids** at:
[MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual: 21.2.6. Connector/Net Connection String Options Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Extra Info:
**How to Insert System.GUID into MySql Database**
----------------------------------------------------------------------
This is a sample table, that we are going to insert the System.GUID:

```
CREATE TABLE `testdata` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `binary` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `char` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Insert System.GUID into MySQL

```
string constr = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr))
{
    conn.Open();

    // Create a System.GUID
    byte[] ba = new byte[16];
    Random rd = new Random();
    rd.NextBytes(ba);
    System.Guid guid = new Guid(ba);

    // Prepare GUID values in SQL format
    string guidForChar36 = guid.ToString();
    string hexstring = BitConverter.ToString(guid.ToByteArray());
    string guidForBinary16 = "0x" + hexstring.Replace("-", string.Empty);

    string sql = "insert into testdata(`binary`,`char`)"
               + "values(" + guidForBinary16 + ","
               + "'" + guidForChar36 + "');";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is uniqueidentifier in MSSQL. Maybe it is similar in MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

Sorry I misunderstood your question. You should use

```
BINARY(16)
```

How you cast that to a System.Guid depends on whether you're using an ORM etc.

Comment: em...sorry. can you explain what is ORM?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

Comment: no, I'm using MySql Dot Net Connector. MySql.Data.DLL

Comment: Hi, DaveHogan, thanks for the clue of ORM. I start to find info about datatype mapping made by Connector/NET. And this what I have found:<br />Start from Connector/NET 6.1.1, CHAR(36) will be returned as System.GUID by default. and version Connector/NET older than 6.1.1, BINARY(16) will be returned as System.GUID. I have added my findings(conclusion) and updated in my question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use EF. Any pointers on how to convert a byte[] (binary16) into a guid? Currently, I do `Guid.NewGuid(myByteArray)`, but this fails sometimes due to the `Byte array for GUID must be exactly 16 bytes long.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a guid as a `CHAR(16)`  binary if you want to make the most optimal use of storage space.
or use `char(36)`

Comment: no. don't use char for binary data. char/varchar/text fields are subject to charset translation rules, and can easily mangle binary data. always use a binary/varbinary/blob type for binary data.

Comment: Hi, Ravindra, I have found out that Start from Connector/NET 6.1.1, CHAR(36) will be returned as System.GUID by default. and version Connector/NET older than 6.1.1, BINARY(16) will be returned as System.GUID. I have added my findings(conclusion) and updated in my question. Thanks for your help anyway.