# Why store GUID as char(36) vs char(32)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

One of our clients requires us to store `GUIDs` as string values.  To do this we store the value as a `char(32)` and strip off the braces and hyphens.  All over the interwebs, however, you see people storing it as `char(36)`.  Why?  Is there a benefit to NOT stripping the GUID of its cosmetic characters?  I'd think you'd want to save the space whenever possible.

Comment: Well, that stripping presumably takes a small amount of time (and effort to get right, of course). Perhaps storage is cheap but compute time expensive in those situations?

Comment: But if you really care about space, you'd store as (in SQL Server, `uniqueidentifier`) the database's GUID data type or if it doesn't have one, `binary`.

Comment: Probably depends what you're doing with it. If you're storing it as string because, say, you want to quickly match against a  GUID that's passed to you as a full string—from a bit of XML, say—then it's going to be faster to do an indexed lookup on a string that's in exactly the same format. Or maybe they're serving it up to clients in the full standard format, and this way they won't need to fiddle with it on the way out of the database... Are you seeing this in SQL Server "all over the interwebs", or just for databases that don't have a native GUID type?

Comment: might be worth looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412341/how-should-i-store-guid-in-mysql-tables as well, even though not an identical question

Comment: It's just a matter of convention. If you see a string with braces and hyphens, you immediately think "hey, that's a GUID!" while a string with only hex characters could be a hash or something else.