# Optimally storing Guid in MySQL: "Data too long for column" even if it should fit to CHAR(16)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm trying to get the most optimized method for storing a GUID as the primary key, which is Binary(16) BUT be able to look at the binary value as text in a MySQL Workbench query. MSSQL makes this easy, why not MySQL?

I have created a table called "hosts" where the primary key is a CHAR(16) called "SystemID". Looking at others example not sure whats wrong.

Why am I getting the error:

> Data too long for column 'SystemID' at row 1

My test ASP.NET method looks like:

```
[HttpGet("add")]
        public ActionResult<string> Add([FromQuery(Name = "systemid")] Guid systemID)
        {
            //https://localhost:44344/api/hostresolver/add?systemid=D3DDCAC9-7DAD-44DF-AD5E-7F9F10AA0EF3

            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(DBSettings.connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    var data = new byte[255];
                    string sql = "INSERT INTO hosts VALUES(?SystemID, ?TrackingID)";
                    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?SystemID", MySqlDbType.Guid).Value = systemID;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("?TrackingID", MySqlDbType.Binary, 255).Value = data;
                        return rowsEffected != 0 ? "Success" : "Failed";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return e.Message;
                }

                connection.Close();
            }

            return "Failed";
        }
```

Since  `Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()` produces 16 bytes I expect it to fit to CHAR(16).

Changing the key to `MySqlDbType.Binary` and setting its value to `systemID.ToByteArray()` works but I can't see what the SystemID value is when doing a query in MySQL Workbench. I should be able to use CHAR(16) but its not working.

Maybe I should to use: "BIN_TO_UUID"?

Comment: do you know how long `System.Guid` is?

Comment: If your column is CHAR(16), you can't use  a `Guid systemID`. Guid is 36 chars long, or 32 in shortform (.ToString("N")).

Comment: Guid is 16 bytes long. You can confirm this by doing Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()

Comment: @JohnB `System.Guid` is exactly 16 bytes. The problem here is that when you try to save GUID as CHAR(16) MySQL will use string representation, which is 36 characters in length

Comment: Also worth to read this: [How should I store GUID in MySQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412341/how-should-i-store-guid-in-mysql-tables). You can follow the solutions provided there to store GUID values as CHAR(n).

Comment: Is CHAR(16) the recommended way to store a GUID in MySQL. I didn't see UUID options like I do in MSSQL.

Comment: maybe [this post](https://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/) can help. But as I think, as Guid is 16 bytes (not 16 characters) you should store it as `BINARY(16)`.

Comment: @zezba9000 please [*do not* keep history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) of your changes in the post. I tried to edit them out - double check if that aligns with what you are asking/trying.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, yes your modification is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Connector/NET stores GUIDs as `CHAR(36)`. If you want to store them as 16 bytes, you need to change the column type to `BINARY(16)` and set `OldGuids=true` in your connection string.

From [Connection Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html):

> The back-end representation of a GUID type was changed from `BINARY(16)` to `CHAR(36)`. This was done to allow developers to use the server function `UUID()` to populate a GUID table - `UUID()` generates a 36-character string.

Note that if you do this, *all* `BINARY(16)` columns in your database will be read back as `System.Guid`. If this isn't desirable, you should stick with the default `CHAR(36)` approach.

If you need more flexibility, [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) (an alternate ADO.NET MySQL Library) supports a [`GuidFormat` option](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/connection-options/), including `Char36`, `Binary16`, and `LittleEndianBinary16`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this CHAR(36) is a horrible approach (as its much slower) vs MSSQL which simply has a proper 16 byte GUID column type? The meta-data / type-system in MySQL seems wonky as hell or super dated. Just going to stick with BINARY(16) for performance and use BIN_TO_UUID in my queries.

Comment: @zezba9000 Correct: MySQL has no built-in `GUID` column type; you have to pick `CHAR(36)` (Connector/NET default) or `BINARY(16)`, then set the `OldGuids` connection string option appropriately.

Comment: @zezba9000 "The meta-data / type-system in MySQL seems wonky as hell or super dated." Yep. There is no `BOOL` column type; you have to use `TINYINT(1)`. The `utf8` character set can't store Unicode text; you have to use `utf8mb4`. The default Unicode collation is pretty dated. All binary data is sent to/from MySQL as hex characters, not as binary. There's probably a lot more.

Comment: I've decided to go with PostgresDB. Seems to be the best option in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the datatype to `LONGTEXT` or even better `char(16)` or even  `binary(16)`.

Comment: why can't you do char(16)? Both binary and char should both represent the same size correct?

Comment: the question was exactly about the fact, that CHAR(16) is not enough

Comment: i usually go for char(36). little bit of wastage is fine with me.

Comment: it is more then twice of wastage. Also, sorting of `CHAR(36)` is slower, then sorting `BINARY(36)` because your server need to check for collation.

Comment: for indexing and fast searching? Do you know, that primary key is **always** indexed?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not a downvoter for this (and I don't know why is this answer is downvoted), because `LONGTEXT`, `CHAR(36)` and `BINARY(16)` actually solves the question asked. I just in doubt is this a **good** (in sense of "good practise") answer?